# How to create a Windows like restore point using Deja Dup ?

Tags: backup

When I click on Deja-Dup Storage, I can see there are some Ubuntu folders,Ubuntu One, WebDav and all the Windows drive visible.

If I select a windows drive for my backup is it going to backup all files including my installed softwares, muzic, movies- everything ?!

When I open/closes a windows drive it mounts and unmounts. If I select that option does it going to cause any mount/unmount problem ?

What is WebDav ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use WUBI then login Windows. Goto c:/ copy the ubuntu,wubi etc ubuntu related folders to a seperate directory (d:/).

If you messed up ,uninstall ubuntu using Wubi from windows control panel (will take only a sec). Again using Wubi Install ubuntu. Should be offline Installation.

Now copy ubuntu related files from d:/ and replace them with the new installation.

Answer (score 2):

Deja Dup is asking you where you want to store the backup files. It packages them up instead of storing them bare in the filesystem like using the `copy` command would, so storing them on remote machines or in different locales isn't a problem.

By default I believe Deja Dup only backs up your home directory. An easy way to 'backup' the package-manager-installed packages, you can do `dpkg --get-selections > ~/Desktop/installed_packages.txt`, and on the new system you can restore it by doing `dpkg --set-selections < ~/Desktop/installed_packages.txt` and then `sudo dselect` and going to `Install`. That will download and install all the packages the package manager had installed on your old system, and by having the installed_packages.txt file on your desktop it will get backed up with the rest of your home directory.

I'm not aware of a way of forcing it to do a full backup, though it may be possible if you read through the documentation for Deja Dup and Duplicity (the program Deja Dup is based on).

Webdav = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV