# How to: Make a "restore point" in Ubuntu, in case I break something?

Tags: apt, backup, synaptic

How can i make a snapshot, a "restore point" in Ubuntu for when im about to try something I think is clever but turns out to be a "oh crap, not again" ?

Comment: Have you seen: http://askubuntu.com/questions/121886/how-to-create-a-windows-like-restore-point-using-deja-dup and http://askubuntu.com/questions/8888/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-restore-point-in-ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you used default installation of Ubuntu - using ext4 partitions and no LVM. In that case you are out of luck.

What you are looking for is feature called snapshots. This feature can be provided either on the filesystem level or partition level.

1. For partition level - google LVM snapshots
2. For filesystem level - you need to choose which file system to use. For example fairly new filesystem btrfs support this feature: https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Incremental_Backup

Answer (score 0):

[image: Found it! Accidentally... heres the instructions...]

Once upon a time, 
long after giving up completely...
In the file menu, there's a command called "save markings"

This solves my problem.